# How to replicate a Laowa 24mm Probe lens in Blender cameras?

Tags: camera

I've replicated plenty of lenses, MM, f/stop, etc. Its all pretty straight forward but this one has me baffled. I've adjusted the camera scale but that doesn't work either. Anyone ever tried to mimic this lens?  If so your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Camera settings don't scale in Blender. If you scale the camera object in the 3d Viewport, all you're doing is changing how big it displays and not the lens or any of the settings int he camera properties.

What you're trying to achieve is a perspective trick. If you shoot anything in real life from a low angle and with a wide enough lens, the subject tends to feel bigger and more imposing.

So to take this into blender, you can do it a couple of ways. Set up a wider lens or scale up your models. The latter I wouldn't recommend. it messes with the realism too much because of lighting and textures etc.

So shoot low, and wide.

Comment: Lockey, I went back and figured out I actually increased the size of the object to give the illusion you're talking about. (Its been a long week) Regardless, it still never looks quite right. Is a 24mm Laowa probe actually a true 24mm?

Answer (score 0):

What matters is the  field of view. Set it to 84.1 degrees and get the camera close to the objects